# Why custom object cannot be a parent in (Parent to child) soql query?

Tags: apex, soql

**Parent Object**: Appointment (Custom Object)
**Child Object**: Opportunity (Standard Object)

My question is can we set custom object as parent in parent to child SOQL query?
I know there are few types:

1. Parent to Child (Standard to Standard)
2. Parent to Child (Standard
   to Custom)
3. Parent to Child (Custom to Custom)

I tested the code below, and it's working perfectly fine. However, I still have some confusion.

```
 public class SoqlDocument 
    {
        Public Static Void Exp()
        {
           List<Appointment__c> oppRec=[Select Id,Name,
                                     (Select Name From 
                                     Opportunities__r) 
                                     From 
                                     Appointment__c];
           System.debug(oppRec);
        
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object being standard or custom doesn't affect whether you can do a child-relationship SOQL query. For example, all of these are valid:

- `SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Contacts) FROM Account`
- `SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Opportunities__r) FROM Appointment__c`
- `SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Appointments__r) FROM Contact`

(There are a very small number of [exceptions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/417647/17819) to this, but they're not worth worrying about)